# C#.net connection to Oracle database error

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, iis

I have a C#.net application that I need to connect to an Oracle db. I built the connection string and datagrid and both show connection and pulling data. Problem is when I try to view the page it gives me this error;

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

I have gone into IIs on my server and set the connection string but still get the error. Here is my page code...
    " ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CFO_INTRANET1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DATE_ENTERED, EMAIL, SUGGESTION FROM CFO_INTRANET.SUGGESTIONS">
       
            
                
                
                
            
        
My Connection,

What am I missing??

Comment: The DSN? ISomg ODBC is quite new - that is about the last thing I would use.

Comment: did you test this connection string outside of your code as a starting point ?

Comment: Why you don't use .NET driver?

Comment: Tested connection string and it works just fine... it is when I try to view the page that gives me a headache.

Comment: You need to configure your ODBC driver in the machine hosting the IIS app.

Answer (score 1):

To setup an ODBC link for a 32bit application you must use:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

To setup an ODBC link for a 64bit application you must use:

```
C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe
```